# PostgreSQL - Best way to incremental export 1000+ tables every 5 mins

Tags: postgresql, bulkcopy

I have 6 PostgreSQL database servers(v11) hosted on some third-party vendor. I don't have access to setup `pg_logical`. Each server has 1 database but 1000+ tables.

So I want to get the data from these 6 servers to my central PostgreSQL database. The sources tables are having PK and last_updated_timestamp columns.

Im just trying to find the best approach to get the data at every 5 or 15mins interval from these tables to my central database server.

My goal is to sync the whole database to Report database server with every5mins interval.

Answer (score 1):

In the central database, define foreign tables using postgres_fdw that point to the other databases. For each table, remember the timestamp from the last time you fetched data. Then regularly run

```
INSERT INTO localtable
SELECT * FROM foreigntable
WHERE last_upd_ts > ...
ON CONFLICT ON (...)
   DO UPDATE ...
```